# Are questions about Chernoff bounds and Lovasz local lemma good fit here?

Tags: discussion, scope

On math.SE, I have asked some questions about Lovasz local lemma

- [Understanding the condition in Lovasz local lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211643/understanding-the-condition-in-lovasz-local-lemma)
- [Two definitions of independence of an event and a set of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211384/two-definitions-of-independence-of-an-event-and-a-set-of-events)
- [independence between an event and a set of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211208/independence-between-an-event-and-a-set-of-events)
- [Understanding dependency graph for a set of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211663/understanding-dependency-graph-for-a-set-of-events)
- [Difference and relation between dependency graph and graphical model?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211400/difference-and-relation-between-dependency-graph-and-graphical-model)

Also, some questions about various versions of Chernoff bounds

- [Which versions of Chernoff bound are applied to Binomial distribution in these examples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213400/which-versions-of-chernoff-bound-are-applied-to-binomial-distribution-in-these-e)
- [How is this version of Chernoff bound derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213621/how-is-this-version-of-chernoff-bound-derived)
- [What are the orders of magnitude for Chernoff bounds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213269/what-are-the-orders-of-magnitude-for-chernoff-bounds)

Although they are purely mathematics questions, the responses there are below expectation.

Since they have important applications in CS, I wonder if I had asked the questions here, what chances I would have got?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the average time-to-answer on math.SE, but your questions are not *that* old. You might want to hold off any action for another couple of days.

Answer (score 7):

They are topics in theoretical computer science so they are on-topic here. If you think your question may receive a more suitable answer here feel free to ask moderators on Math.SE to migrate them.

If the question is not yours then the issue is more complicated. The question would be on-topic here but migrating a question is a decision that should be made by Math.SE.  Please see [this meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0) on their meta for more information.

One thing you can do is that if you are interested in a question and the answers on Math.SE do not answer your question in a satisfactory way you can post a new follow up question here linking to that question and pointing out more specifically why you feel the answers are not satisfactory.

Comment: That said, they *are* purely mathematical questions, and CS mostly by application (although some feel machine-learning-ish). I consider it unlikely that we can provide better treatment, but I have nothing against having such questions here. (A big number would shift our focus uncomfortably, but some are fine.)

Comment: Mathematics and computer science are not disjoint topics. In fact almost all of theoretical computer science can be categorized as mathematics, and a large portion as pure mathematics. If a topic is extensively studied by computer scientist then it is indeed likely that a computer scientists can provide a better answer. Lovasz Local Lemma is such an example. Anyway, I think both theoretical and practical computer science are on-topic on this site and we don't have a rule that one should be dominant.